# Price demand function to revenue function

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, optimization

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring this out, I found the price demand function in the previous question, based on that I am supposed to find the revenue function. I am a bit confused by the wording and what I should do.

Isn't this the revenue already based on the correlation between price and demand.
See picture attached for the first question that I sovled.

Thanks so much for your help

[first question process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAyJc.jpg)

[prompt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gipsM.png)

[prompt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSVu4.png)

Comment: Hi Mario and welcome to MSE.  You should include the text from the images in your question properly using mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and make your title a question. Looks like this is a simple pair of simultaneous equations. Do you know what those are? Do you have Chiang, fundamental methods of mathematical economics?